# Override jquery's $.ajax default behavior of parsing data and creating a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to use `$.getJSON` or `$.ajax` to pull geojson data from my server and load it onto google maps using `map.data.loadGeoJson(data)` the data is good because this works using `map.data.loadGeoJson('/static/json/data.json')` as well as another method of loading the data using just `$.getJSON` however when i try to use the two together i'm getting this error `Error parsing [object Object]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` because the data is trying to be parsed twice. Is there a way to override `$.ajax` default method of parsing the data so I can leave it to `map.data.loadGeoJson(data)` I tried using `processData: false` however this does not seem to be working. Heres the code...

does not work

```
  $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        method: "GET",
        url: "/static/json/data.json",
        processData: false,
        success: function(result){
            map.data.loadGeoJson(result);
        }
    });
```

this method works

```
 map.data.loadGeoJson('/static/json/data.json');
```

as well as this one

```
  $.getJSON("/static/json/data.json", function(data) {
        $.each(data.features, function(key, val){
           $.each(val.geometry, function(i, g){
                if (g ==="Point") {
                    x = 1;
                } else{
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(g[1], g[0]);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng,
                        map: map
                    });
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

Comment: `dataType: "text"` throws the same error except the json data gets displayed in the console. Whats up with that?

Comment: Maybe [stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) it before passing it on? What does `result` look like when you print it before passing it on to the next call?

Comment: @Jasen result gets turned into a javascript object `Object {type: "FeatureCollection", features: Array[6]}` which has a drop down with all the geometry objects in it. Stringfy also throws a parse error.

Answer (score -1):

What is `result` value from the first method?? Have you try like :

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    method: "GET",
    url: "/static/json/data.json",
    processData: false,
    success: function(result){
        map.data.loadGeoJson(jQuery.parseJSON(result));
    }
});
```

Comment: Using `dataType: "json"` that should not be needed.

Comment: this can't work because `loadGeoJson()` takes a url as argument per map docs. Not to mention that `result` is already an object that doesn't need to be parsed

Comment: this throws no error however there are no markers. Could it be possible that `map.data.loadGeoJson('/static/json/data.json')` in of itself is an ajax request?

Comment: @Groovietunes yes it is, that's why you pass url to it

Comment: @charlietfl well now I feel dumb....even so, I'm going to need a way to pass query strings to the server this doesnt seem possible with just `map.data.loadGeoJson('/static/json/data.json');`

Comment: @Groovietunes you can still pass data to map from your ajax if that's what you want to do, just use a different method. Maps APi is well documented and it should be easy to figure out alternatives

Comment: It appears you can build your query strings directly into the URL.